Windows Server 2022 .Net 4.7.2 System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser Error randomly thrown IIS Version 10.0.20348.1
I have been banging my head against the wall today trying to troubleshoot an error that is thrown inconsistently for the past few weeks. The stack is below (some class and namespace names have been redacted for privacy). I'm reaching out to the Stack Community for help! Internet searches have not been helpful. Thanks in advance.
Cloud environment is AWS and applications are running on EC2. OS is Windows Server 2022 Datacenter. The application is an IIS App using .net 4.7.2 . IIS version is 10.0.20348.1
I can see that the SQL is executing in less than 1 second using an MSSQL Extended event, but the application is throwing an error for timeout of 6 minutes reached. I also see tds_flag ErrorFoundBeforeLogin, SessionIsKilled via extended event tracing.
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): The wait operation timed out
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.ExecuteReader(DbCommand command)
   at *****.*****.*****.*****.******.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<ExecuteReader>b__0()
   at *****.*****.*****.*****.*****.*****(DbCommand command, Action methodToWrap)
ClientConnectionId:******
Error Number:-2,State:0,Class:11 


Please try to run this  sql statement exec sp_updatestats;.

Hi @JasonPan please provide details on why you think this is a database statistics issue?

Hi h24601, does it works for you?

@JasonPan please provide details as to why you think database statistics are related to tds parser error in .net 4.7.2 ?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/statistics/statistics?view=sql-server-ver15
